# Django 1.8 Passing data between pages with using form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-1.8

I already have codes and it doesn't working. But I'am looking for solution or practice on how to pass data between pages with using form. Should I work with hiddenfields or sessions?. I am ready to change or rewrite my codes. I am open the other suggestions, thought.

Here is my codes

**forms.py**

```
class applyForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    basvuru_mesaji = forms.CharField(required=True,error_messages={'required':'Bu alanı boş bırakmamanız gerekiyor'}, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'full','placeholder': 'Başvuru mesajınızı buraya yazınız'}))
    tcn = forms.IntegerField(required=False, error_messages={'invalid':'Numara dışında karakter girişi yaptınız'}, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'full','placeholder': 'T.C. Kimlik Numaranız'}))
    hidden = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required = False)

    class Meta():
        model = apply
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class apply(models.Model):
     tcn = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='T.C.N :', null=True)

     basvuru_mesaji = models.TextField(verbose_name='Başvuru Mesajı')
```

**views.py**

```
def form_for_apply(request):
    form = applyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_join = form.save(commit=True)
        new_join.save()

        basvuru_mesaji = form.cleaned_data["basvuru_mesaji"]
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/apply_ok/')       

    context = {"form":form}
    template = "apply.html"
    return render(request, template, context)

def apply_ok(request):
    allfield = apply.objects.all()
    print allfield  
    form = applyForm(request.GET)
    context = {"form":form}
    #print context.data 
    template = "apply_ok.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**apply.html**

```
          {% csrf_token %}          
          {% if form.errors %}
             {{ form.errors }}
          {% endif %}        

          {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
            {{ hidden }}
          {% endfor %}  

           <div class="mTopTwe">      
              <label for="{{ form.basvuru_mesaji.id_for_label }}">
                {{form.basvuru_mesaji.field.label}}
              </label>
              {{ form.basvuru_mesaji.errors }}
              {{ form.basvuru_mesaji }}
            </div>
```

**apply_ok.html**

```
<div class="mTopTwe">
 {{form.basvuru_mesaji.data}} {{ form.hidden.data }}
</div>
```

Comment: You can serialize the form data and store it in session and manage it on your won. Or use form wizard which does the management already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**render_to_response** solved my problem.

```
return render_to_response('apply_ok.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'form':form}))
```

**forms.py**

```
def apply(request): 
    form = applyForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid(): 
        new_join = form.save(commit=True)
        new_join.save()

        basvuru_mesaji = form.cleaned_data['basvuru_mesaji']    
        return render_to_response('apply_ok.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request,{'form':form}))      

    context = {"form":form}
    template = "apply.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using django **[wizard-form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)** for passing data between pages.